# How to store result of a LINQ statement executed in foreach to a variable for future use?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to store multiple values that satisfies specific condition to lstfile.
For that I declare:

```
List<AlbumPhotos> lstfile =  new List<AlbumPhotos>();
```

And used the below code to get the id of just installed records in T_SelectionListDetails:

```
idList = (from s in context.T_SelectionListDetails
                          orderby s.ID descending
                          select new AlbumPhotos { ID= s.ID }).Take(i).ToList();
```

where i is the variable that hold how many records saved right now.Then I need to join the T_SelectionListDetails table  with T_UserAlbumDetails .Following code is used for that and it will return multiple result but I can't get the entire result but only one.

```
foreach(var item in idList)
{
    lstfile = (from s in context.T_SelectionListDetails
               join p in context.T_UserAlbumDetails on s.UserAlbumDetails_ID equals p.ID
               where s.ID == item.ID
               select new AlbumPhotos
                       {
                           virtualPath = p.VirtualPath,
                           ID = s.ID
                       }).ToList();
           // lstfile.Add(t);
     }
```

how can I get the full result?

Comment: so, couldn't you see all the records in `lstfile`?

Comment: It is better if you show the schema of your tables and the output you need!

Comment: instead of setting the result as lstfile, you can create a temp variable and add it to a list. For example, new YourFileType temp = LINQ statement; YourList.Add(temp);

Comment: yes I did the same as temp = LINQ statement; YourList.Add(temp); but I got two errors:1)Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AP.WebApp.Models.AlbumPhotos>.Add(AP.WebApp.Models.AlbumPhotos)' has some invalid arguments D:\Projects\Album\SourceCode\Dev\AP\AP.WebApp\Controllers\ProductSpecificController.cs 173

Comment: 2)Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AP.WebApp.Models.AlbumPhotos>' to 'AP.WebApp.Models.AlbumPhotos' D:\Projects\Album\SourceCode\Dev\AP\AP.WebApp\Controllers\ProductSpecificController.cs 173

Comment: Do you want to pass all the `item id` at once instead of passing it through for loop ?

Comment: https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `AddRange` to add the elements of one collection to the end of the other list.

```
foreach(var item in idList)
{
    var lstfile1 = (from s in context.T_SelectionListDetails
               join p in context.T_UserAlbumDetails on s.UserAlbumDetails_ID equals p.ID
               where s.ID == item.ID
               select new AlbumPhotos
                       {
                           virtualPath = p.VirtualPath,
                           ID = s.ID
                       }).ToList();
      lstfile.AddRange(lstfile1);
}
```

Comment: I am surprised how it was different than my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the lstfile in foreach loop which will replace old value in each new iteration. And after the loop it would contain the value that is assigned in last iteration of foreach loop.

Better you update your code :

```
foreach(var item in idList)
{
var lstRows = (from s in context.T_SelectionListDetails
           join p in context.T_UserAlbumDetails on s.UserAlbumDetails_ID equals p.ID
           where s.ID == item.ID
           select new AlbumPhotos
                   {
                       virtualPath = p.VirtualPath,
                       ID = s.ID
                   }).ToList();
       lstfile.AddRange(lstRows);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to pass all the `ID` at once instead looping through it.

```
           lstfile = (from s in context.T_SelectionListDetails
                      .Where(c => idList.Select(n => n.ID)
                      .Contains(c.ID))
                      join p in context.T_UserAlbumDetails on   
                      s.UserAlbumDetails_ID  equals p.ID

                      select new AlbumPhotos
                      {
                        virtualPath = p.VirtualPath,
                        ID = s.ID
                      }).ToList();
```